# Is there a word for 'within ten units of'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, numbers

Is there a word that can used like decade, but when talking about units not years?

For example, everyone knows that:

- 2006 is within a decade of 1998
- 1989 is in the same decade as 1984

However, when you try to do the same for units, it's not so easy:

- 45 is within ten of 38 (sounds a bit weird, but is acceptable)
- 76 is in the same ten as 74 just doesn't sound right at all!

Comment: Wikipedia: "A collection of ten items (most often ten years) is called a decade."

Comment: aside from **decade** itself, when one is needed a new word is coined. For example, **percentile** when discussing groups of percentages.

Comment: "Within ten of" is completely fine. That doesn't sound weird at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some Romance languages, there isn't such word in English. When we talk about countables, however, we can always say...

> dozen - (noun) "A group of 12 people or things":  A dozen oranges, half a dozen doughnuts (6 doughnuts). ("dozens of" = a large number of people or things)
>
> score - (noun, plural same) "a group of 20 things, often used in combination with a cardinal number e.g. fourscore = 80)": A score of men lost their lives in the battle.
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dozen

Although some dictionaries define "ten" as "something having 10 units or members"  You couldn't possibly say: "I'm buying *two ten* apples or *half ten* oranges.

Comment: Indeed. English is not French.  French has [*dizaine, centaine, cinquantaine, **douzaine,** huitaine, quarantaine, quinzaine, soixantaine, trentaine, **vingtaine***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dizaine).  We have only the bold ones, although sometimes you can get away with a century, at least if you’re a centurion.

Comment: @tchrist Tres bien monsieur tchrist. +1 pour être bien versé en français.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you get away with a century if you play snooker or cricket as well. I even believe it's highly valued, although I will not profess any real knowledge of either sport.